# First quadrant is positively invariant SIR

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the system:
\begin{align}
S' &=  -rSI \\
I' &= -\gamma I + rSI \\ 
R' &= \gamma I
\end{align}
where $0 < r < 1$ and $\gamma > 0$.

I want to prove that the region $Q = \{ S > 0, I > 0, R > 0\}$ is positively invariant. I have proved that the region $\{ S \geq 0, I > 0, R > 0\}$ with the following combination of arguments:

1. The plane $I = 0$ is made of fixed points, so the region $I > 0$ is positively invariant.
2. $R' > 0$ in Q, so the R-component is an increasing function in $Q$.
3. Given a trajectory $(r(t), s(t), i(t))$ with ($r(0), s(0), i(0))\in Q$ suppose that there exists $t_2$ such that $s(t_2) < 0$. Then there exist $0  < t_1 < t_2$ such that $$s(t_1) = 0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad s([t_1, t_2]) \subset (-\infty, 0]$$
   By the MVT, there exist $\tau$ such that $t_1 < \tau < t_2$. $$s(\tau) = \frac{s(t_2) - s(t_1)}{t_2 - t_1} = \frac{s(t_2)}{t_2-t_1} < 0$$ Notice it must be $s(\tau) < 0$.
   But $$s'(\tau) = -r s(\tau) i(\tau) > 0$$ because $i(\tau) > 0$ because of point 2.

I just need to discard the posibility of a trajectory reaching $S = 0$. A similar MVT argument shows us that in that case, it should be $S = 0$ from that point, but I have not been able to discard the posibility of such trajectories. Maybe the fact that $S + I + R$ is constant can be useful.

I would like to solve the problem by a purely qualitative analysis, not by solving the equation.
Thanks in advance.

**A posible solution** If there was a solution with $s(t) = 0$ for $t> t_1$ then the trajectory in $t > t_1$ is given by $i(t_1) = i(0) e^{-\gamma (t-t_1)}$ and $r(t_1) = r(0) e^{-\gamma (t-t_1)}$. Therefore, $(r(t), s(t), i(t)) \to 0$ when $t \to \infty$ but $r(t) + s(t) + i(t) = r(0) + s(0) + i(0) = C_0 > 0$. I would strongly prefer a qualitative solution though.

Comment: Why the long argument for $S=0$? You can apply the same as you did to $I$ in point 1.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I don't know what do you mean. The plane $S=0$ is not made of fixed points, is it?

Comment: No, but of curves lying completely inside it. By uniqueness, no curve from outside this plane can cross it. This is a general principle for systems that can be written as $\dot x_k=x_kf_k(\vec x)$, which is the form of the S-I sub-system here.

Comment: @LutzLehmann OK, I get it now. Does that also discard the case (via uniqueness of solution) in which an orbit enters the line and stays in it?

Comment: Yes. No crossing, no branching in or out.